# Keeping the distance between 2 divs constant

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML markup -

```
<div class="bar">
<p> Example Text </p>
</div>

<div class="dynamic-height">
 <div class="box">
  <p> Example Text 1</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
This is footer
</div>
```

and the following CSS -

```
.bar{
     height:20px;
     width:100%;
    }
 .box
    {
      float:left;
      width:50px
      height:50px;
      border:1px solid black;
    }
.dynamic-height
    {
     min-height:50px;
     width:100%;
    }
. body
    {
       height:200px;
    }
.footer
    {
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    }
```

Following are the rules that are expected of these divs -

1. The div with class "dynamic-height" will have more

   elements
   added to it dynamically using javascript. So its height will be
   dynamic
2. The div with class "footer" will always have to be in the bottom and the distance between the the dynamic height and footer div should always be 10px; (margin: 10px)

**Coming to the problem -**

The moment I add a dynamic "p" element using javascript, to the div with class "dynamic-height", the height of this div increases and if I keep on adding the "p" elements the height increases and then it overlaps with the footer div.

***All I want is to keep a 10px distance between the footer div and the dynamic-height div at all times***

Answer (score 3):

just add margin-top to the footer to always have a 10px space

```
.footer
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working. I think I'am not able to explain my concern here.

Comment: I did a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5b30tgn/5/) and was able to figure out the way

Answer (score 1):

Clear the left float from your `.box` div on your `.footer` div:

```
.footer{
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    clear:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

That should do it. The `.footer` div is hanging on the re-positioned `.box` div.

Comment: Your **clear:left**  gave me directions towards the solution that I was looking at.  Since the dynamic-height  div's height was dynamic, adding **_overflow:scroll_** along with a **_height_** fixed the height to the max that it could expand.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-bottom in your .dynamic-height class as below `margin-bottom :10px;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the it did not seems to work. Have updated the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5b30tgn/5/) that  would make my case clear as far as my question is concerned.

```
<div class="bar">
<p> Example Text </p>
    <input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Add box"/>
</div>

<div class="dynamic-height" id="dyn">
     <div class="box">
      <p> Example Text 1</p>
     </div>        
</div>
<div class="footer">
This is footer
</div>
```

I was able to take the hint from tahdhaze09 and used it combination with setting the overflow property to auto, for the dynamic-height div.

As my Original question, perhaps was not clear enough, was to make the distance between the two divs constant, with one being of dynamic height. So for this div the overflow property did the magic